# Get Posts including their Taxonomy with one query in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress

With

```
$posts = get_posts([
    'post_type' => 'post_foo',
]);
```

I can get all the posts, but it doesn't include the categories. Looping through the posts and retrieving the categories for each entry is bad for performance.

Is there some way to get the posts data including categories with one query? Or which approach is the most efficient one?

It would even help, if the `get_posts` would give the list of `term_id`s for a post. Then I could get all the categories from DB, then all the posts, and afterward merge the data. So 2 queries, instead of `1+n`

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you need all the categories as a key to the post object, you will need to use raw queries.

Not sure why you cant use the get_posts and then call `wp_get_post_categories($post->ID)` to get an array of all the post categories.

Comment: @Ovidash the problem is, when there are many posts, then getting categories for each post will trigger seperate DB request, so for 100 posts there will be 1 + 100 requests. Usually it is not good for performance.

Comment: true, then the only solution for you is to query everything in a raw query using $wpdb and just using mysql "select" and construct the query as you need.